# Why are utopic packages installed by default on 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I've installed Ubuntu into VirtualBox 5.0.16 from a 14.04.2 iso image.  I didn't do anything fancy, just accepted the defaults all the way through the installation process, except choosing to install SSH server.

This is what I find in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, which must have been run automatically by the installation process.

```
Commandline: apt-get --yes upgrade
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install linux-generic-lts-utopic
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install pciutils
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install usbutils
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install biosdevname
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y install tasksel
....
```

Notice one of the things it is installing is `linux-generic-lts-utopic`, even though this is trusty, not utopic.  Usually that wouldn't bother me, if the packagers want me to have utopic headers, fine.  Except when I do `apt-get upgrade` now, I get the message:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Why is it by-default installing things that it doesn't know how to upgrade?  I understand that can happen when you start mucking around with non-standard repositories, but I haven't done anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "utopic" packages installed by default in 14.04.2. However, 14.04.2 is the hardware enablement release, which includes the kernel version which was included in Utopic (14.10), by default. This is packaged as `linux-generic-lts-utopic` as you see in the package name.

The packages are held back, not because the system doesn't know how to upgrade them, but because they require installing new packages (a new kernel image). You will need to use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install them from the CLI.